# I want to filter and get the code working with ONLY FLOAT NUMBERS

Tags: php, filter, floating-point

I have this code below, and I want to know why is entering in the first "if", if for example in the $temp variable there is a number like 500, 5, 70, or whatever. I'm looking to filter FLOAT numbers only, like the filter says

```
$temp = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_REQUEST["temp"]), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));
$se = trim(htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($_REQUEST["select"]), ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"));

if (!empty($temp) && filter_var($temp, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)) {
   if ($se == "celsius" && $temp >= -273.15) {
         $result = round(32+(1.8*$temp), 2);
         echo "$temp ºC = $result ºF";
   } else if ($se == "fahrenheit" && $temp >= -459.67) {
        $result = round(($temp-32)/1.8, 2);
         echo "$temp ºF = $result ºC";
   } else {
        echo "El valor introducido no puede menor que -273,15 si es Celsius, o menor que -459,67 si
          es Fahrenheit";
   }
 } else {
      echo "Rellene el campo con un número decimal, por favor";
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `is_float()` ?

Comment: I have switched filter_var with is_float, but is not working. I have tried the var_dump to see what was happening, and even If I give a number like 80.45, the value of is_float is false. Maybe the input type of the form is giving trouble? Because in my form, the input type is "text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter_var` will actually turn a value from `int`, `string` to a `float` number. That means that if you call:

```
filter_var(400, FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)
filter_var('400', FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT)
```

the result of both calls would be the float number `400.0`.

If you actually need to see if the given number has a decimal separator you could check it like:

```
if (is_numeric($temp) && strpos($temp, '.') !== false) {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution worked, but is that solution like "brute force"? Because is not actually looking for is the number is float or not, just if the number has a "." But yes, obviously if a number has a dot is float but well, I thought is_float may have worked but not

Answer (score 0):

I can´t get the filter to work too right now, i am unsure about the reason in this case.

But try to use the `is_float()` function of PHP

Like this:

```
if (!empty($temp) && is_float($temp) {
```

Answer (score 0):

may be because of the mixed data type. Check with `var_dump` to verify the data type.
Use `is_float()` instead of `filter_var`